# Tillers and stolons in grasses

Tags: botany

In many grasses, tillers develop roots at their nodes etc.. Those roots can hit the ground and subsequently anchor in the soil, so eventually the tillers end up like something that is very hard to separate from stolons (I often see this in Agrostis gigantea).
Are there objective criteria for separating tillers and stolons at all times?